# Removing "RE:" (and alikes) from email subject using RegEx class

Tags: c#, regex

I need to remove the leading *RE:* from a subject and it's definitely not my day today, because I don't get the match and obviously am missing something simple. My predecessor made it abundantly clear that the *Substring* approach works but I just can't stand bad technique. :)

```
//emailSubject = emailSubject.Substring(4);
emailSubject = Regex.Replace(emailSubject, @"^.{0, 3}:\s", "");
```

The way I see it, we should find the beginning of the string and get between zero and three characters followed by a colon and a space. Then, this junk should be removed.

The computer disagrees, though, and I'm out of ideas. What simple thing do I miss here?!

Comment: "I can't stand bad technique". Some would argue that the overhead of `regex` over simple substrings _is_ bad technique ;)

Comment: I'm open for alternative ways, of course. But keep in mind that it could be **any** string such as *ang:*, *sv:* etc.

Comment: The overhead doesn't really matter IMO. It's readability. In this case I think the readability of `IndexOf(": ")` and regex is approximately the same.

Comment: Personally I think your pattern is overly general.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the space after the comma:

```
@"^.{0,3}:\s"
```

Comment: I'm both impressed by the accuracy and a bit afraid. It's not human to see such errors. Humans are supposed to break down in cry at them, haha. Explanation: I coded the expression in a different text editor that "helped" by spacing in after a coma. This was an **excellent answer**!

Comment: @KonradViltersten: To take away your fear: I tried it in LINQPad. The space was my second try, the first was something else.

Comment: This kinda works, since it relies on the fact that `:` is rarely used in email title, except for the automatic insertion by the mail composer.

Comment: @nhahtdh: I answered the direct question of the OP on how to make the expression work. But I agree with your and CodeCaster's point that this might remove too much. If this is an issue the OP needs to define for himself.

Comment: LINQPad? Is it a class in .NET?

Comment: Disregard the last comment, please. I just rediscovered the black magic of googling stuff. Really not my day today.

Answer (score 3):

If you are concerned about multiple FWD chains (and alikes) and multiple client languages:

```
public static string ClearSubject(string originalSubject)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"^([\[\(] *)?(RE?S?|FYI|RIF|I|FS|VB|RV|ENC|ODP|PD|YNT|ILT|SV|VS|VL|AW|WG|ΑΠ|ΣΧΕΤ|ΠΡΘ|תגובה|הועבר|主题|转发|FWD?) *([-:;)\]][ :;\])-]*|$)|\]+ *$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    originalSubject = regex.Replace(originalSubject, string.Empty);

    if (regex.IsMatch(originalSubject))
    {
        return ClearSubject(originalSubject);
    }

    return originalSubject;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all sort of stuffs such as `re` and `fwd` with the following regex:

```
^(?>(?:re|fwd) *: *)*
```

The regex above is to be used with [`RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx).

It can even take care of multiple reply and forward, such as:

```
re: re : RE: fwd  : re: fwd:  About meeting tomorrow
```

Comment: Suppose we want to make it work for many languages and even custom prefixes. That'd produce a nasty long string, wouldn't it?

Comment: @KonradViltersten: Well, yes, of course. If you have better solution, please share.

Comment: @KonradViltersten and you would like to filter "New:" from the subject? Just use a list, not a regex.

Comment: I have a better solution (for my needs). It's listed in the question. See what @danielhilgarth excellently pointed out. The list that you're suggesting assumes that I know all the custom prefixes that might occur and I won't have that information. Sorry.