# Strip re: etc from SQL Linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I need an email parser that attaches incoming emails to its corresponding ticket.

If the subject of the email includes something in the format of a ticket number, then I search on that and I'm done. That's been working for years.

Now, we want to search by subject for a matching ticket title.

I found [Removing "RE:" (and alikes) from email subject using RegEx class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16395814/) which is great at stripping re: etc. from the incoming subject. But, we have instances where the ticket title includes the `RE:`. I anticipate that it could include `FW:` and `FWD:` and the mixed and lower case versions of all of those.

What's the cleanest Linq or SQL query to find a match? I'm familiar with `Replace()`. Can I string those together? It's awfully ugly to string together the, what, 16 Replaces to catch all of the case versions, but I suppose I could live with that.

And, how is the performance of doing that? I suppose I can `ToLower` both side, and that should work? That probably would not hurt my subject title match. That's down to three Replaces.

I did find one page that said that using regex in the query ends up retrieving all of the data, which could be expensive. Does that apply to `Remove`, too? I am already filtering by incoming email address to get a single client, so I'm not going to be running these against the entire database. So, maybe regex is viable?

Is there something better? Reminder, we're using Entity Framework.

Thanks

PS: I am aware that some simple subjects might get multiple hits.  "Error" or "Email problem."  I'll order by descending date, and hope that catches most of those.

----- Edit: -----

Forgive me, I thought my description was pretty thorough.  This is a pretty well contained problem.  Stated slightly differently, I have some common extraneous text fragments in a VARCHAR field, and I'm looking for the best way to search against that field that ignores those few common text fragments.

Here's the current state of my FindExistingTicket() method.  I have started the filtering by client, but hadn't finished that by the time I saw these comments.  (I was away from my desk for a couple of hours.)

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Given a from address and a subject, see if we can find a ticket to match.
    /// to match.  Either the formatted ticket number is in the subject.
    /// Or, the subject is identical to a ticket title.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="from">The From address.</param>
    /// <param name="subject">The subject string.</param>
    /// <returns>The ticket found, or null.</returns>
 public Ticket FindExistingTicket(string from, string subject)
 {
    Ticket ticket = null;

    // If the subject is null then there's not going to be a match.
    if (subject == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    // First look for a formatted ticket number.
    Match m = TicketNumRegex.Match(subject);

    if (m.Success)
    {
        // Make sure a ticket with that number actually exists.
        ticket = db.Tickets.Where(a => a.TicketNumber == m.Value).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    // If we have a ticket, then we're done.
    if (ticket != null) return ticket;

    // Check to see if we know this email address
    Contact contact = db.Contacts.Where(a => a.ContactStatu.Status.Equals("Active") && a.email.ToLower().Contains(from)).FirstOrDefault();
    if (contact != null)
    {
        Client client = db.Clients.Where(a => a.id == contact.customer_id).FirstOrDefault();

        // Search for a ticket where the Subject matches the Title.
        // First, strip off any re: or Fwd:
        // If we want multiple languages, per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16395814/
        // @"^([\[\(] *)?(RE?S?|FYI|RIF|I|FS|VB|RV|ENC|ODP|PD|YNT|ILT|SV|VS|VL|AW|WG|ΑΠ|ΣΧΕΤ|ΠΡΘ|תגובה|הועבר|主题|转发|FWD?) *([-:;)\]][ :;\])-]*|$)|\]+ *$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(?>(?:re|fwd|fw) *: *)*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        string strippedSubject = regex.Replace(subject, string.Empty);

        // Among open tickets, if we find more than one ticket with this Title, we grab the last one.
        List<Ticket> tickets = db.Tickets.Where(a => OpenIDs.Contains(a.Status_ID) && a.Title.Replace("re:", "") == strippedSubject).OrderByDescending(a => a.LastQueueDate).ToList();
        if (tickets.Count() >= 1)
        {
            ticket = tickets.First();
        }
    }
    // else we don't know the email address, so just fall through and return null

    return ticket;
 }
```

So, right now, if there's a RE: in the ticket title in the SQL database VARCHAR field, I don't get a match.  The examples of ticket titles that include RE: and FW: are manually Copy&Pasted from email subject lines, so I'm not going to be stripping them out before they get committed to the database.

After posting this, as I was walking out the door, it occurred to me that once I filter the tickets by client, I'm already going to have a list in memory.  So, I should be able to cheaply use regex there.  Assuming, that is, that EF will allow me to do that.

I'm happy to hear any other ideas.

Comment: If you’re looking for a specific string - ‘ticket title’ - then why not just search for the titles and ignore everything else? You could use a table-value parameter (if your version of EF supports that)

Comment: I don't understand, where do you have the email? or are you working with a list of strings?

Comment: You need to share your entity class with us, what data store are you using, what sort of LINQ you've already got... it's very hard to tell what you're trying to do here.

Comment: If the subject argument to FindExistingTicket is not stripped and the subject in the database field is not stripped, why are you stripping the subject parameter, only to have to apply that same logic inside your LINQ expression/query? Why not just use the raw subject in your query? Then, once you have a matching ticket, strip the offending characters from `ticket.Title` in C#.

Comment: Why not just use `s.EndsWith(original)`. Anyway performance will be not good in any cases. Database cannot use indexes here.

Comment: The reason I'm stripping them is that there are a lot of instances where those will change.  As the email chain grows, some email programs will see "re:" and then it'll add "RE:" and now we have "RE: re:".  And so on.  Lots of ways those can get prepended onto the subject line.

Another way to say it:  I can't guarentee that those will remain consistent.  And, if I'm stripping them on one side, I'm going to have to strip them on the other.  There's no good way for me to figure out which to leave behind.

Comment: I tested it with EndsWith, and it worked in my straightforward tests.  But, I can imagine situations where there's a RE: in the middle of the ticket title.  Probably not often, but I can see it happening.  So, the subject would have that internal RE: stripped, and EndsWith would no longer match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After realizing that I have a list in memory, I ended up being able to use the same regex on both the subject and the title in the LINQ.  That's good, because they should get stripped in the same way.  Here's the relevant portion of the final code:

```
// Check to see if we know this email address
Contact contact = db.Contacts.Where(a => a.ContactStatu.Status.Equals("Active") && a.email.ToLower().Contains(from)).FirstOrDefault();
if (contact != null)
{
    // Grab a list of only this client's open tickets.
    List<Ticket> clientTickets = db.Tickets.Where(a => OpenIDs.Contains(a.Status_ID) && a.Company_ID == contact.customer_id).OrderByDescending(a => a.LastQueueDate).ToList(); // sort descending strip

    // Search for a ticket where the Subject matches the Title.
    // First, strip off any re: or Fwd:
    // If we want multiple languages, per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16395814/
    // @"^([\[\(] *)?(RE?S?|FYI|RIF|I|FS|VB|RV|ENC|ODP|PD|YNT|ILT|SV|VS|VL|AW|WG|ΑΠ|ΣΧΕΤ|ΠΡΘ|תגובה|הועבר|主题|转发|FWD?) *([-:;)\]][ :;\])-]*|$)|\]+ *$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(?>(?:re|fwd|fw) *: *)*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    string strippedSubject = regex.Replace(subject, string.Empty);

    // If we find more than one ticket with this Title, we grab the last one.
    List<Ticket> tickets = clientTickets.Where(a => regex.Replace(a.Title, string.Empty)
        == strippedSubject).OrderByDescending(a => a.LastQueueDate).ToList();
    if (tickets.Count() >= 1)
    {
        ticket = tickets.First();
    }
}
// else we don't know the email address, so just fall through and return null
```

Thanks for helping me think this through